# Why do some Python submodules not import automatically?

Tags: python, import

I am trying to use IBM's Qiskit, which is a Python library for quantum computing circuit design and simulation.

In particular, I need to use submodule `qiskit.aqua.components.oracle` which is a submodule of `qiskit.aqua.components`. However, when I try

```
import qiskit.aqua.components
```

only some, not all, of submodules inside `qiskit.aqua.components` get imported.
[image]
 I have to import `qiskit.aqua.components.oracle` manually.
[image]
 If I take a quick look at the source code (https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/tree/master/qiskit/aqua) I don't see any particular reason this should be the case. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you know that `.oracles` isn't actually imported? Don't rely on the autocomplete. Actually type it out and test it.

Comment: @Stuart, yes, if I only try "import qiskit.aqua.components" and then try to make a class instance beloinging to .oracles I get the message "module 'qiskit.aqua.components' has no attribute 'oracles'".

Comment: I can't answer why it behaves like this, but their own [code](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/search?q=qiskit.aqua.components.&unscoped_q=qiskit.aqua.components.) shows that they use the full import path.  Notice all the `from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizer import COBYLA`. So, I'd say use the full import path to each "module".

Answer (score 0):

When you import a (sub-)module, the module itself decides what members it exposes. Further submodules are not automatically included. In your case, you import `qiskit.aqua.components` and the `components` module decides via its `__init__.py` what member it exposes. The following is an example structure:

```
qiskit/
├── aqua
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── oracles
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` files define the content of each (sub-)module. In the above example they are all empty. So let's import `qiskit.aqua.components` and inspect the module:

```
>>> import qiskit.aqua.components
>>> qiskit.aqua.components
<module 'qiskit.aqua.components' from '/tmp/qiskit/aqua/components/__init__.py'>
>>> dir(qiskit.aqua.components)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
>>> qiskit.aqua.components.oracles
...
AttributeError: module 'qiskit.aqua.components' has no attribute 'oracles'
```

Since `components/__init__.py` didn't choose to expose its submodules, they are not accessible from within that module. We can change that by adding `from . import oracles` to `components/__init__.py`:

```
$ cat qiskit/aqua/components/__init__.py 
from . import oracles
```

Now let's import the module again (a restart of the Python REPL is required due to [module caching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules)):

```
>>> import qiskit.aqua.components
>>> dir(qiskit.aqua.components)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'oracles']
>>> qiskit.aqua.components.oracles
<module 'qiskit.aqua.components.oracles' from '/tmp/qiskit/aqua/components/oracles/__init__.py'>
```

As we can see, the `oracles` module is now accessible.

For your specific example, the [`qiskit/aqua/components/__init__.py`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/7c2c2e546e9002e758ff6b25f98a9a594589bd6f/qiskit/aqua/components/__init__.py) file does not import the `oracles` submodule and so you need to import it separately in order to access it.

---

A note on `import x.y.z`: this first imports `x`, then `x.y` and eventually `x.y.z`, making those modules available. But it stops there and doesn't go any deeper in the module nesting, so any other submodule needs to be imported manually (e.g. `import x.y.z.foo`).